# Add customer name to woocommerce email-header.php heading

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

I want to update the header saying "custommer_name sent a GIFT for you".It's 
not working !!

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_header">
                <tr>
                    <td id="header_wrapper">
                        <h1><?php
                              $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
                              echo $order->get_billing_email() . $email_heading; 
                     ?></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This site is meant for asking for help with your own code, so it's expected that you show what you've tried and then ask if anyone knows why it's not working. Having said that, gift card functionality is not part of Woocommerce's core functions, so it would at least help if you mentioned what plugin you're using!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to override class or create your custom email type, I can give a short hint on the modifications to be made in the class further you can override in your child theme or plugin if you don't want to loose the changes on woocommerce update.

In `/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-completed-order.php`

On line 37:

```
$this->placeholders   = array(
    '{site_title}'   => $this->get_blogname(),
    '{order_date}'   => '',
    '{order_number}' => '',
    '{order_name}' => '',
);
```

Here I added `{order_name}`,

Then on line 86

```
if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
    $this->object                         = $order;
    $this->recipient                      = $this->object->get_billing_email();
    $this->placeholders['{order_date}']   = wc_format_datetime( $this->object->get_date_created() );
    $this->placeholders['{order_number}'] = $this->object->get_order_number();
    $this->placeholders['{order_name}'] = $this->object->get_billing_first_name();
}
```

Here I defined First name to `{order_name}`, now you can use this placeholder in woocommerce email settings at `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=email&section=wc_email_customer_processing_order`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't solve my problem exactly but I get the idea and your answer will help me later thank you again.